# MySQL function declaration. Not works from PHP. Run's ok from phpmyadmin. Not creates function

Tags: php, mysql

I have function to cal miles distance:

```
DELIMITER //                                                                                      
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS distance_miles//                                                      
    CREATE FUNCTION distance_miles(lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT)                
    RETURNS FLOAT(120)                                                                            
    BEGIN                                                                                         
        DECLARE pi, q1, q2, q3 FLOAT;                                                             
        DECLARE rads FLOAT DEFAULT 0;                                                             
        SET pi = PI();                                                                            
        SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180;                                                               
        SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180;                                                               
        SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180;                                                               
        SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180;                                                               
        SET q1 = COS(lon1-lon2);                                                                  
        SET q2 = COS(lat1-lat2);                                                                  
        SET q3 = COS(lat1+lat2);                                                                  
        SET rads = ACOS( 0.5*((1.0+q1)*q2 - (1.0-q1)*q3) );                                       
        RETURN 6378.388 * rads * 0.621371192;                                                     
    END//                                                                                         
DELIMITER ;
```

I run this as 1 query from phpmyadmin. It run's Ok. But i dont see this in routines table in information_schema.

Also, when am trying run this from php i got an error

```
 $mdb->query($mdb->mes("
     DELIMITER //                                                                                      
         DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS distance_miles//                                                      
         CREATE FUNCTION distance_miles(lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT)                
         RETURNS FLOAT(120)                                                                            
         BEGIN                                                                                         
             DECLARE pi, q1, q2, q3 FLOAT;                                                             
             DECLARE rads FLOAT DEFAULT 0;                                                             
             SET pi = PI();                                                                            
             SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET q1 = COS(lon1-lon2);                                                                  
             SET q2 = COS(lat1-lat2);                                                                  
             SET q3 = COS(lat1+lat2);                                                                  
             SET rads = ACOS( 0.5*((1.0+q1)*q2 - (1.0-q1)*q3) );                                       
             RETURN 6378.388 * rads * 0.621371192;                                                     
         END//                                                                                         
     DELIMITER ;                                                                                       

 "));
```

this one:

*****error:1064*****
**CALLED:[Resource id #8]***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\r\nDELIMITER ~~                                                                ' at line 1**
in db query: [\r\nDELIMITER ~~

Pls help me, what happens? Completely dont understood this.

1. How to look if function exists?
2. It will appear in information_shema table ROUTINES?
3. why is problem with php running this query?

====

SELECT ROUTINE_TYPE, ROUTINE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

Also - dont show this function ... strange this all...

---

Also this:
SHOW CREATE FUNCTION distance_miles

Answers: 
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1305 - FUNCTION distance_miles does not exist

...

Comment: You might find your MySQL connection does not allow multi-queries, or setting the DELIMITER. How are you connecting to your database?

Comment: Am uxing simple code:

$this->_link = mysql_connect($_host,$_user,$_pass);
      if ( ! mysql_query($qu="use $_base;", $this->_link))

I need allow multiqueries somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query` doesn't support multiqueries. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

You just need to remove the `DELIMITER` lines, split the queries by yourself, and the `CREATE FUNCTION` should work.

```
 $mdb->query($mdb->mes("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS distance_miles"));
 $mdb->query($mdb->mes("CREATE FUNCTION distance_miles(lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT)                
         RETURNS FLOAT(120)                                                                            
         BEGIN                                                                                         
             DECLARE pi, q1, q2, q3 FLOAT;                                                             
             DECLARE rads FLOAT DEFAULT 0;                                                             
             SET pi = PI();                                                                            
             SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET q1 = COS(lon1-lon2);                                                                  
             SET q2 = COS(lat1-lat2);                                                                  
             SET q3 = COS(lat1+lat2);                                                                  
             SET rads = ACOS( 0.5*((1.0+q1)*q2 - (1.0-q1)*q3) );                                       
             RETURN 6378.388 * rads * 0.621371192;                                                     
         END                                                                        
 "));
```

Comment: completely dont understood, why php not made already this support ... this is a must ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$mdb->query($mdb->mes("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS distance_miles"));
 $mdb->query($mdb->mes("delimiter $ 
CREATE FUNCTION distance_miles(lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT)                
         RETURNS FLOAT(120)                                                                            
        DETERMINISTIC BEGIN                                                                                         
             DECLARE pi, q1, q2, q3 FLOAT;                                                             
             DECLARE rads FLOAT DEFAULT 0;                                                             
             SET pi = PI();                                                                            
             SET lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180;                                                               
             SET q1 = COS(lon1-lon2);                                                                  
             SET q2 = COS(lat1-lat2);                                                                  
             SET q3 = COS(lat1+lat2);                                                                  
             SET rads = ACOS( 0.5*((1.0+q1)*q2 - (1.0-q1)*q3) );                                       
             RETURN 6378.388 * rads * 0.621371192;                                                     
         END $                                                                      
 "));
```